# Determine user account status with pyad

Tags: python, python-3.x

How might I find if a user is active using pyad? I know how to get their department, username, name etc. but I don't know the proper name for activity status. Here is my code for getting their department and name:

```
 x = aduser.ADUser.from_cn(i)
 dept = x.department
 name = x.displayName
 act = x.?
 users = i, dept, name, act
```

"i" is a list of usernames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pyad import  aduser

user = aduser.ADUser.from_cn("User Name")
user_atrri = user.get_user_account_control_settings()
print(user_atrri['ACCOUNTDISABLE'])
```

False - Means Account is Enabled
True - Means Account is Disabled